# How to use POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE in odoo container?

Tags: docker, odoo

I need to hide password of postgres in odoo container like in postgres container, when we create new container postgres we can pass env variable POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE, and the content of Dockerfile of postgres 9.6 contains this block of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeo pipefail
# TODO swap to -Eeuo pipefail above (after handling all potentially-unset variables)

# usage: file_env VAR [DEFAULT]
#    ie: file_env 'XYZ_DB_PASSWORD' 'example'
# (will allow for "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD_FILE" to fill in the value of
#  "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD" from a file, especially for Docker's secrets feature)
file_env() {
    local var="$1"
    local fileVar="${var}_FILE"
    local def="${2:-}"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ] && [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        echo >&2 "error: both $var and $fileVar are set (but are exclusive)"
        exit 1
    fi
    local val="$def"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ]; then
        val="${!var}"
    elif [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        val="$(< "${!fileVar}")"
    fi
    export "$var"="$val"
    unset "$fileVar"
}
```

How we can do the same code in odoo image?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your whole odoo.conf as a secret, create your service and add that secret with the --secret file and point to the path /run/secrets/${MY_SECRET} on your entrypoint with the -c flag on the odoo [command](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/cmdline.html)